# Consulta de error al intentar consumir un web servicie de JAVA desde el cliente de ASPX (MIME PDF)

Tags: webservice, web, pdf, aspx

Buen dia compañeros mi pregunta es la siguiente estoy corriendo un cliente en ASPX  , el cual esta consumiendo un web service de JAVA el detalle es al momento de intentar almacenar un archivo de tipo mime me marca el siguiente error si me  devuelve  el pdf pero con el error siguiente

El cliente encontró el tipo de contenido de respuesta 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<12890-48835438.1589554941841.IBM.WEBSERVICES@GNPASPROAL06>"; boundary="----=_Part_12506_569094261.1589554941841"', pero se esperaba 'text/xml'.
Error de la solicitud con el mensaje de error:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Serializes a class named Group as a SOAP message.  
        //XmlTypeMapping myTypeMapping =
        //    new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Group));
        //XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(myTypeMapping);

        WSGNP.WSImpresionImplService WSA = new WSGNP.WSImpresionImplService();
        WSGNP.RequestImpresion WSImpresion2 = new WSGNP.RequestImpresion();
        WSGNP.ResponseImpresion Impresion2 = new WSGNP.ResponseImpresion();

        WSImpresion2.usuario = "xxx";
        WSImpresion2.password = "xxx";
        WSImpresion2.poliza = "390410876";
        WSImpresion2.version = "0";
        WSImpresion2.tipoAttachment = "MIME";

        Impresion2.poliza = "";
        Impresion2.error = "";
        Impresion2.version = "";


        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        Response.Write(WSA.impresionPDF(WSImpresion2));
        Response.End();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]